# Pandas | Compare two CSV files and return matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

so basically im trying to compare two CSV files and return matches.

CSV1: Contains a list of Keywords.

```
keywords

Apple
Banana
Orange
```

CSV2: Contains random content.

```
content

I like Apples
Banana is my favorite Fruit
Strawberry Smoothies are the best
```

If I include the Keywords in the Code like this... I get a decent result.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('CSV1.csv')
result = df[df.content.str.contains('Apple|Banana|Orange')]
```

Since the Keyword-file is getting bigger. I'm looking for a way to extract the Keywords from a csv and check for matches instead of putting all the Keywords in the Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that by using the pandas isin() function (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

The pseudo code would be:

```
# put the csv1's list to lower case
list_csv1 = [i.lower() for i in list_csv1]

# use the isin() function
# again, put the content to lower case
result = df[df.content.str.lower().isin(list_csv1)]
```

Putting everything to lower cases isn't mandatory but is a good way to normalize your data and prevent missings.